# Someone deposited money in my account for business but Bank of America says it's unauthorized

Tags: scams, bank-of-america

I found a job online. They told me a customer has sent money to my account and I should send it to their managers who are outside the USA. They deposited twice. The bank called me and said it's an unauthorized transaction and started an investigation. The fraud department told me that if the sending bank insists, they could investigate further.

Am I getting into any trouble? I withdrew the first amount but didn't spend anything. What will happen?

Comment: In addition to being in trouble with police, FBI, Department of Homeland Security etc for being involved in a money-laundering scheme, you are also in trouble with whoever put the money into your account. The money you have withdrawn (as well as the money not yet withdrawn) is _"their"_ money and they may well come looking to collect it as cash, with drawn guns etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a foreign bank manager name me as the kin of a deceased customer if I don't know the person?](http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/23754/can-a-foreign-bank-manager-name-me-as-the-kin-of-a-deceased-customer-if-i-dont)

Comment: You're being scammed. Clearly the bank was able to identify the scam and is working to stop it.

Comment: You didn't find a _job_ online, you agreed to participate in a money-laundering scheme or other fraudulent scheme. You have a "contract" saying that you will send the money that you receive from a "customer" to someone else.

Answer (score 20):

This is a typical scam. Yes, you just got listed with the terrorists as trying to launder money internationally.

Terrorist organizations will try to find someone in the US who will accept deposits from overseas sources then send that money to one of their operatives.

Cooperate with whichever police force comes knocking on your door. Pray that it isn't Homeland Security. They do not need warrants.

Comment: Yes but I didn't send money to them. Most of the amount still in my account rest of them in my packet. I didn't send money to them

Comment: Still get in trouble?

Comment: Unlrss you can prove that you had no idea you were being scammed, you might get in trouble. I'd suggest you take this to your local police rather than waiting for them to come to you. If you are lucky, they'll recognize that you're the victim, not the criminal. Next time, if something sounds suspicious, ___hang up___.

Comment: Ok when they send email I told them seem fraud I'm not gonna send money to you. I didn't send any money. I withdraw first one but didn't spend either. Still in my wallet. Bank of America start investigation. They said up to 90 days. Should I hire attorney? Any recommend?? I'm on probation. I don't wanna get in trouble.

Comment: @Onur I suggest you get in touch with whoever doing the investigation at BoA and ask them what they want to do with the money. Don't spend it, it is not yours. I don't think FBI is going to put you in a hole, as it doesn't sound that you've actually broken any laws yet, but you most definitely cannot spend the money - that would be stealing.

Comment: If you are on probation then check the conditions of your probation to see if you have already violated probation. Call your probation officer and explain what is going on. You want the probation officer in your corner when the Department of Homeland Security knocks on your door.

Comment: For now you are under suspicion because the authorities don't know if you were working with the money launderers or not. Cooperate fully and their suspicions should go away.

Comment: I have contract with company. The customer  the send the money to my account and I would send the money to their account with money order or money gram. But I didn't send the money some of the amount still in the account some of them still in my packet. 2 questions. They do investigation what's the worst case after investigation done? And did I really violated probation?

Comment: @Onur you're really asking about legal issues you should be discussing with your lawyer under privilege and not on an open Internet forum.

Answer (score 6):

Basically, any time someone claims they put money into your bank account, or send you a check, or something similar, and then asks you to send money to someone else, it is a scam. What you need to do: 1. Under no circumstances whatsoever must you ever send money to anyone. 2. Talk to your bank and ask them for advice.

The money that gets put into your bank account isn't real. It has been paid with a forged check, or a stolen credit card number, or a hacked or faked bank account. Your bank will figure this out eventually, and then they will take that money away. It may take many weeks, but the money will disappear.

Meanwhile, any money that you send to someone is real. It's your money. When you send it, it is gone. Your bank will hold you to that.

So in your case if they say they pay you $6,000 for a job, but put $10,000 into your bank account and ask you to pass $4,000 on to someone, the $4,000 you pay comes out of your bank account, a long time later the $10,000 comes out of your bank account, and you owe the bank $4,000. Plus sometimes the job involves real work that obviously doesn't pay.

An alternative is that this is money laundering, in which case you would become a criminal by being involved.

Answer (score 1):

This is very similar to what was asked in this question:

[Scam or real?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/67941/scam-or-real-a-woman-from-facebook-apparently-needs-my-bank-account-to-send-mon)

This is a real winner of a scam, because it always finds someone gullible enough to fall for it.  No stranger sends you money just to be a nice guy.

This version of the scam is one I've seen on job-hunting sites.  They'll promise you a job, and then they say they'll send you a check for equipment and supplies, but you need to send most of the money back to them.  As long as they find victims, they'll continue to find more refined techniques to stay ahead of the authorities, and it'll change just enough that people won't recognize it for what it is.

***AVOID THIS AT ALL COSTS!!***

I hope this helps.

Good luck!