# Company is asking me to send my personal info so they can send Bitcoin to my personal account in order to pay customers using my personal account

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, job-offer

I added a screenshot of an email that a company I applied for this week. They are asking for my Name, Number and Bank name so they can send Bitcoin currency to my personal account in order to “buy goods for my customers“. This is for a customer service representative position and I am confused on why they don’t use their own bank account and are wanting to use mine to pay for THEIR customer goods.
Is this a scam?

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is a scam.

Comment: Either a scam or money laundering.

Comment: Pretty much any question on this forum that includes the words "Is this a scam" is always answered with a resounding YES.

Comment: @Rocky I saw *one*, about a year ago, that wasn’t a scam.  **ONE…**

Comment: @Rocky See [Have there been any "Is this a scam?" questions that the answer was "No"?](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2542/) on Meta. The particular one I remember seeing was [I'm supposedly eligible for an inheritance from a distant relative. Offer appears to be legitimate](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/101935/).

Comment: No real company will ever ask you to use a bank account registered as a private account under your name for company business.  When they ask you to do that, it's because they want to do something criminal where you are either the victim, the person taking the fall, or both.

Comment: Odds are they will transfer stolen funds to you, which you will then convert into actual bitcoin for them.