# Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I Dm this guys he’s really nice and says he only wants a companion I talk to him for awhile and we agree to $300 a week but he wants me to cash app him 25$ so he can trust me. I even asked if I could give him 10 and send him the rest later and he said okay. He said he’d send me the money as soon as I did.

Comment: SCAM ?? YES !! YES !! YES !! YES !! YES !! YES !!

Comment: [Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy)

Comment: Didn't even have to read the text of the question to answer :-)

Comment: Voting to leaving this open,, as we don't seem to have a good answer for this variant of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advance-fee_scam

Comment: @RupertMorrish **Romance scam** ??

Comment: He claims he needs money to trust you; but why would you trust him?  (And him saying that he will give you money isn't a good reason; it's trivial to lie about)

Comment: It's funny that these questions come up enough for this site to have a sugar daddy tag

Answer (score 4):

100% scam.

And to add some salt:  It is likely a [**Sugar daddy bot**](https://www.reddit.com/r/grindr/comments/ah3023/lots_of_sugar_daddy_bots_lately_i_get_23_a_day/).