# Sugar Daddy/Bank Help

Tags: debt, scams, sugar-daddy

I met this guy on Twitter who was interested in a sugar baby with someone to speak with, get to know, etc. He lives in IL apparently and I’m in the east coast. Initially he wanted me to buy a $200 GC and give him my bank login info so he can pay off my credit card debts - the GC is apparently for charity. I said no and we agreed that I’d get a $50 GC and he’ll give me his bank information to post the CC payment and show him the receipt.

Thoughts? Is this a scam? Can I get in any legal trouble here, or what’s the risk?

EDIT: He did not ask for MY info, he offered to give me HIS ACCOUNT INFO. It seems some of you are confused, because I’m not an idiot and would never give someone my bank info.

Comment: More importantly, the meaning of "sugar" in "sugar baby" seems to have been lost.

Comment: Stack should start a Sugar Daddy Community for all of these questions and provide a bot that replies to all of them with "IT'S A SCAM !!!!!!!"

Comment: "I’m not an idiot and would never give someone my bank info."  Which is good and all, but... if giving your bank creds is so bad, **why would he give you his?**

Comment: Regarding your edit, the account info he have you wasn't his.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy)

Comment: Do we need a different site for "shugga daddie" questions?

Comment: The confusion is because in your question you say  "Initially he wanted me to buy a $200 GC and **give him my bank login info** so he can pay off my credit card debts"

Comment: _he’ll give me his bank information_ - There exists fake banking websites which would allow your scammer to "give" you details to log into "their account", and would have the ability to show any sort of activity that they want you to believe has happened. The account they give you could also have been stolen from someone else.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, it's a scam.

My guess would be that the person you're talking to is going to give you the bank account information from a different person that he scammed (probably someone that fell for his initial suggestion).  You buy a gift card (no charity needs a gift card, they're much happier with real money) that you send to him.  When the person that he scammed notices the charge and reports the theft, the store that sold the gift card knows it was you that made the purchase.  The scammer has a nice $50 gift card, you've got a couple of detectives investigating you for theft and no practical way to point them at the scammer who will have most likely already discarded whatever account they were using.  Best case, you convince the cops that you were a victim, pay back the $50 that you stole (unintentionally), and don't end up with a criminal record.  The worst case is much worse.

Of course, it's possible that the scammer is involved in money laundering or, less likely, is willing to give you a legitimate $50 in order to make you trust him before he has you do something else that will create legal problems for you.

Answer (score 14):

In a world with email money transfer, why anyone would need your bank info to *send* you money is beyond me.

This is 110% a scam. Stop all communication with this person.

Answer (score 7):

Yes it is a scam.

*hint* if anyone, ever, asks for your bank details and it is not the teller in the physical bank, it is a scam. Clear and simple.

Comment: Not even the teller in the physical bank should ask you for details.

Comment: And as a corollary: if anyone _offers_ their bank details like this, it won't be _**their**_ bank details they are offering... it will be another victim's bank details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes this is a scam.

If I'm following this right you're being used as a money mule. The account info your sugar daddy will give you isn't his. It's info he stole from someone else. You will then use that info to buy a gift card. At best, he's spending someone else's money. At worst you're being used as a mule or cutout and you'll be asked to buy more things with "his" account later. When it all shakes out your email address, ID, street address, etc. are the ones connected to these fraudulent transactions.