# Sugar daddy bitcoin scam?

Tags: scams, cryptocurrency, sugar-daddy

I met a sugar daddy online who claims he cannot use cashapp or paypal to compensate me and can only use bitcoins. I made a coinbase account and now he is asking for my coinbase login so he can "load my account with his cryptography watcher and it will be loaded"

I am just skeptical because i have read about cases of people getting scammed with money laundering in regards to bitcoins since it leaves a digital trail of where the bitcoins gets transferred.

Could he be attempting to scam me? What could he do with my bitcoin account if he were to have access to my login?

Comment: `for my coinbase login so he can "load my account with his cryptography watcher and it will be loaded"` He doesn't need your login to pay you in crypto coins. He is trying to steal your coins and maybe your identity. All in all a SCAMMMMMMM !!!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy)

Comment: Compensate you for..... what, exactly?

Comment: If it says "sugar daddy", then the odds that it's a scam are about 999999 :1.

Answer (score 8):

I don't know CoinBase, but usually these Bitcoin portals allow you to create a bitcoin address for incoming funds where he can send the coins to.

If that's not enough for him, something fishy is happening.