# Sugar momma asking for bank details

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

So this lady hit me up on Instagram and asked if I’d maybe be interested in being her sugar baby. We talked a bit but she wants my bank login and password. I asked for picture proof and she sent a picture but I still don’t know if I should believe it. I understand that “she” can take out my money but I only have $15 so there’s not that much of a risk. If I give her my info, what’s the worst that can happen?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy)

Comment: Never, ever, give anyone your password to any account.

Comment: Why on earth would you think that somebody sending you their picture on the internet is any sort of security? You may only have $15 in the account, but if she uses that account to write a bad check for $1500, you'll be the one who's on the hook for it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the fact that this question is being asked is a bit scary, since you must have contemplated sending or not sending before posting the question. I was actually close to downvoting the question, but choose to answer hoping this helps you or someone else. Your specific question wasn't whether to send or not, but i'll answer that regardless. No. [insert your favorite swear word here] No!

Now on to your actual question, what is the worst that can happen if you send "her" your bank details? (For the rest of my answer, we'll assume she's a she since she sent picture proof)

1. Credit to Charles E. Grant who pointed out in the comments that she could write a bad check. She could write one, she could write several.
2. She could use your account as a pass-through to receive the proceeds of defrauding some [widower of his $200,000 life savings](https://nypost.com/2020/02/12/fake-lover-scams-elderly-widower-into-spending-life-savings-on-huge-lion-statue/), moves it to your account and out of it. You'd be the first suspect.
3. She could use your account to fund purchases on the dark-web...you know, buy stuff like drugs, pay for child pornography, murder for hire, or do any number of things that would land you in serious hot water with one or more law enforcement agencies
4. She could file [fictitious tax returns](https://www.aarp.org/money/scams-fraud/info-2020/id-theft-and-tax-returns.html) and use your account to receive fraudulent refunds
5. She could use your account to convert [bitcoin ransoms](https://www.businessinsider.com/florida-city-paid-600k-hackers-shows-us-unprepared-for-threat-2019-6) to cash. All of a sudden, you're sleepy-eyed at your front door, in your boxers staring at a squad of FBI agents raiding your house.

After these 5 examples that popped into my head without even thinking too hard, I can assure you, you probably can't imagine the worst thing that will happen to you if your bank details/access fall into the wrong hands.

I'll also add that given the fact that you're asking this question, it is likely that you might have already unknowingly passed on seemingly harmless details to help her build a more complete profile that expand the range of crimes/identity theft that could be performed at your expense...not necessarily financial expense (I think your $15 is probably safe)...more like your time...in jail.