# Is he scamming me?

Tags: united-states, sugar-daddy

My sugar asked me to create a new bank2go ive never used it before has no money no anything and he is asking for my account and routing number and online access should I give it to him ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy)

Comment: Take a minute to browse the [sugar-daddy](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sugar-daddy) tag on this site.

Comment: "My sugar asked me.." I knew it was a scan two words into the question. The whole sugar situation is rife with scams and probably best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is a scam. No don't give him anything, especially not account numbers. See the many other questions on this site on same subject