# Sugar mama threatening to send someone to kill and blackmail me. Is it a scam?

Tags: scams, sugar-daddy

I will admit I am ashamed at what I did, and a little anxious, but I’ll also share this in hopes that someone will either learn from this, or that someone will know what to do (or even give advice).

I was naive roughly two weeks ago, and a sugar mama (or possibly scam) found me on a dating app. I was intrigued by the idea, being a young adult, as well as afraid to say no, so I went along. We started talking and eventually I gave my SSN, address, name: basically info I shouldn’t have.

There were no sexual favors involved and they seemed nice, though they had broken English and repeated themselves often (signs I noticed afterwards).

Eventually I got the hint that something was wrong, told them I would not give information, and blocked the number. A few days after I blocked the first number, another number texted me, but it happened to be the same person.

This time, they were supposedly “pissed” and threatened my life, as well as to send someone after me and my family, saying I could not hide and to watch my back. Even going as far as to use my info for bad things (ironically, they’re threatening to do all that they promised they wouldn’t do before).

I eventually told my mother, as scared as I was, and we’re now working on trying to stay safe. So far we called police for precaution and we’re in the process of getting a new number for me + new SSN, but I was wondering as to if we should genuinely worry.

Is this a scam? Is this a real but obsessive sugar mama? Are we doing the right thing? Or is it too much?
(I apologize if this was too long.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy)

Comment: They probably texted you from a burner phone.  Did they send you any emails?

Comment: Regarding the part about your physical safety, you'll probably be fine. The scammers are likely in a different city, state, even country (as hinted by the broken English), and don't have the resources to act on their threats. Even if they did, it is not worth it to them risking life in prison for. However, you did good in reporting this to the police anyway. Even though the police will likely not have the resources or the will to go looking for the scammers, at least you did your part in fighting back against this filth of a human.

Comment: In that order?  Kill first then blackmail?

Comment: @PeteB. If the dying took months, it would be possible, if one twisted some definitions.

Comment: Yes, it's a scam.  No, it's not a real sugar mama (I would personally recommend staying away from sugar mamas, real or not, in the future.)  The threats are almost certainly just bluster to try and convince you to re-engage.  It sounds like you've done everything you can (ie: getting a new SSN, new phone number) but I wouldn't count on any kind of closure to the issue.