# i think im being scammed by a sugar daddy

Tags: sugar-daddy

so i'm female 18 and i was looking on a website for a sugar daddy, i started talking to one and we moved to texting, he then asked for my banking info which i turned down and asked if he used paypal. he said no and that he had been scammed threw that before so he doesn't use that anymore. after talking to him for a little i stupidly gave him my info. we had talked about amounts before and he was going to send me a couple hundred but then all of a sudden he said he was going to send me extra so that i could go buy him some gift cards and send him the codes. i said no, changed my password and told him i didn't want to be his sugar baby anymore and blocked him. he then made a new phone number and proceeded to somehow get back into my account and send me almost 1000 dollars and is now threatening me. saying that i need to go buy him some steam gift cards 450 dollars worth scratch off the back and send him the codes. i said no and told him that i would go to the police. he all of a sudden gave my a paypal email and said to send him the money back but i'm scared it'll be a fraud and it'll make my account go into the negatives.

so i was stupid and panicking and i sent him 450 to get him to stop constantly calling my phone with new numbers and harassing me. i was only on the websites because my family is struggling to pay our bills. my paychecks have been going to my parents and my savings is almost wiped out because of it and im supposed to move in august.

Comment: Good on you for shutting it down at least. Don't spend/transfer the money, it likely wasn't his to begin with. I'd probably contact your bank to let them know what happened and see what they say, but there are quite a few similar questions on the site, perhaps someone can point you to one of those with more definitive steps you should take.

Comment: Anyone with your bank account number and routing number and your name can send you money.

Comment: It's getting to the point where I can see the words "sugar daddy" in the thread title and my instinct is to reply "you're being scammed" without reading the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Am I being scammed by a sugar daddy?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/109924/am-i-being-scammed-by-a-sugar-daddy)

Comment: @Matthew: It's really interesting.  This is the one tag on this site where every question is the same and every answer is also the same.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you already know this is a scam.  Do not send him any money or gift cards.

The best thing to do is to tell the bank that the money you received is from a scammer, and let them take care of it.  You will not get to keep the money in any case, as it did not belong to the scammer and it does not belong to you.  By telling the bank before they figure it out, it will support your innocence in the matter.

Finally, stop going to sugar daddy websites.  It is all a scam.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you are being scammed.

The $1000 in your bank account has been stolen from another victim. It will be removed from your bank account as soon at that victim or their bank notices.

You should contact PayPal / Steam and advise them that you have been a victim of fraud and want to reverse the $450. Be prepared for them to say it is not possible, and for you to be $450 out of pocket.

You should also report this to the police.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's a scam.

The $1,000 will be reversed back out of your account. Contact PayPal and tell them about the $450 you transferred. If they say they can't help you get your money back, then consider this a $450 lesson learned.