# Am i being used for bank fraud

Tags: banking, fraud, identity-theft, money-laundering, theft

I have been speaking to a girl in Nigeria she promised to visit me but but twice didn't show up said she loved me although never met. Asked for money multiple times asked for bank details and says she wants to be with me. Now she has deposited a lot of money into my account and its due to clear today. Is this scammers using my account to leave no trail to themselves. Also got my address picture and postcode and claiming it her late fathers insurance money. Any help appreciated thanks

Comment: Yes, it's a scam..

Comment: Can't tell if you're even serious or trolling. This is either made up or the most obvious scam I have ever heard of.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ghana scam and direct deposit scam?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/76981/ghana-scam-and-direct-deposit-scam)

Comment: How do you know the money is going to clear today?  Did SHE tell you that?  When exactly a deposit will be cleared is not generally publicized by the banks.  More importantly, the bank will let you withdraw money before it has cleared, as a convenience to you.  WHEN (not if) the deposit fails to clear, the bank will claw back the funds from your account, and you'll be out however much of that money you spent.

Answer (score 13):

**Every single sentence of your description is a red flag for "scam".**

- *a girl in Nigeria* I'm sorry for real, honest Nigerians but so many scammers claim to be Nigerian that it's a red flag.
- *promised to visit me but but twice didn't show up* Scammers don't show up in person and have an excuse
- *said she loved me although never met* Real people don't fall in love without meeting.
- *Asked for money multiple time* That's what scammers want.
- *asked for bank details* The only reason someone wants your bank details is to steal money from it.
- *deposited a lot of money into my account* People don't do that without a reason.

Contact your bank *right now* and tell them what is happening. Get them to close your account and open a new one. Change any passwords you have given out. Tell the bank that you think the deposit might be fraudulent and ask how they recommend handling it.

Comment: Mention any West African country? SCAM. It's one of the ways they filter out savvy and worldly people, along with weird spelling mistakes, and (of course) desperately implausible financial propositions.

Answer (score 3):

This is a standard scam.

### It WON'T clear today.

The actual clearing time is guesswork - nobody knows until it clears.

If the deposit is rejected/does not clear/fails/bounces... **you will need to give ALL the money back**.  Those are the rules. If you don't like the rules, then don't use the banking system.

When you deposit money from an unknown source the bank puts a "hold" on the money for a FIXED period of time that IS A GUESS as to how long it will take to *actually* clear.

When the bank releases the hold, **that does not mean it has cleared**.  That only means the bank has hoped/guessed it has cleared.

"Hold Release" is NOT the same thing as "Cleared".  The scammer will work really hard to convince you otherwise. It's all lies.

When scammers make deposits like yours did, those deposits are deliberately rigged to take an extra long time to clear.  Get it?

1. the bank releases its hold.
2. Crunch time: they must convince you to take the money out of the bank and send it back to them *via a different, non-reversible method*... BEFORE,
3. the original funds bounce, leaving you holding the bag!

By "holding the bag" I mean **You MUST give ALL the money back**. It doesn't matter if you don't have it anymore, you are the person responsible for making sure the money is good. So you will be out all the money you sent onto them, and will have to make it up from your own sources.

It's the same crime as "passing bad checks" - and yeah, you can go to jail for it.  Though more likely they'll sue you for it, burn down your credit report, and **you'll become "unbanked"** - banned from the banking system for 7 years, and having to go to those pink check-cashing places to cash your paycheck and pay utility bills.

Emptying and closing your bank account could have collateral damage to rent, car payments, credit card bills etc.

The reason you might be subject to criminal penalties (most likely, non-jail, since the goal is to get you to pay) is that a reasonable, impartial person should have suspected that it was a scam, given "Nigeria" and the probability of the girl who "needs" money sending money to you instead.

### They say "Nigeria" *for a reason*

Microsoft Research [wrote an academic paper](https://gizmodo.com/why-nigerian-scammers-say-theyre-from-nigeria-5919818) on why scammers willingly say they're from Nigeria when so many people know offers from there are scams.

Romance scams are particularly hurtful, because they get you emotionally "invested" in the lies being true.