# Military man says he's in Syria he is working for US Army

Tags: credit-card, scams

How and what do I need to do. I did give my information on a credit card. He paid off my card and then asked me to get him itunes 100 dollars each of the full amount and send him the money. Is this a scam he said this is for him to send to his Dad and daughter.

Comment: Did a **complete stranger email you** and then ask to send him money via iTunes?  Let me repeat... **COMPLETE STRANGER**.

Comment: Protip: If you have to ask whether something is a scam, presume the answer is *yes*. Scams that look scammy are *far* more prevalent than legit scenarios that look scammy.

Comment: See answers to https://money.stackexchange.com/q/68110/19497

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I received $1000 and was asked to send it back. How was this scam meant to work?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/68110/i-received-1000-and-was-asked-to-send-it-back-how-was-this-scam-meant-to-work)

Answer (score 21):

He is not a military man. He is not in Syria. He is definitely not in Syria working for the US army, because the last thing that anyone in Syria working for the US army would do is tell a stranger about it. That kind of information could get the person killed, and likely would get them court martialled (thanks jamesfq), so that's a lie.

Since it sounds like you gave your credit card number to a scammer, you call your credit card company's fraud helpline RIGHT NOW and tell them what you did and ask them to close down your credit card right now. Don't worry that they might be laughing at you, they've heard worse.

Don't send anyone any iTunes gift cards that you paid for. They are easy for scammers to turn into money, and there is no way you can get your money back.

Comment: Passing out that kind of information could also get military personell court martialled, if their commanders happen to find out.

Answer (score 10):

This is a scam. Please call and close the credit card immediately. Do not contact the scammer or send him anything.

There is no reason for a US Military man to do something like this. The scammer is no Military man or in Syria.