# Money Transfer Question

Tags: credit-card

I am trying to perform a landscaping job for someone. However, they are telling me that the ex-owner of the house he is trying to buy does not accept credit cards. He is asking me to pay for the closing fee by sending me his credit card information and sending the ex-owner a certain amount to pay for it while giving me the downpayment for the landscaping work that is needed to be done. Should I be cautious of this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Stranger sent me $12,100](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123855/stranger-sent-me-12-100)

Comment: Absolutely, exact same thing. Thank you!

Comment: If the other person is the **ex**-owner, surely there are no fees left to pay? If they're **not** (yet) the ex-owner, why are you performing a job for someone that isn't, and might not become, the new owner? I'd stay clear until the house has changed hands.

Comment: That was my concern. I was waiting until confirmation for the house to be paid for by the person wanting the landscaping done.